# Bevel modifier produces very different miter to bevel tool?

Tags: bevel

I was surprised to find that the bevel modifier handles the points where edges join quite differently to the bevel tool.

Below, I've got two boxes - the one on the left beveled with the bevel tool and the one on the right with the bevel modifier. The boxes were identical before beveling.

There's an edge joining two corners across a flat surface (see **A** in the picture). The bevel tool introduces extra edges here to produce a better result than the bevel modifier which leaves this area as it was.

Is there anything I can do to get the bevel modifier to behave like the bevel tool here?

The other difference between the two was that the bevel tool did the right thing at the inner corner whereas with the bevel modifier, I had to manually set *Miter Outer* to *Patch* to get a similar result at **B**. It would be nice if the modifier version was as smart as the tool version, i.e. could automatically do the right thing here.

**B** is fine, though - I could resolve that. But **A** is a bigger issue, the bevel tool produces a much better visual result - is it possible to achieve the same result with the bevel tool?

[image: bevel]

[image: boxes]

[image]

Comment: Well, the answer is giving you the solution, just a quick additional information: even the Bevel _tool_ would behave like the Bevel _modifier_ if you wouldn't select all edges but only those above certain angles - because that's the default setting of the _modifier_: _Limit Method: Angle_, above 30°. The _modifier_ is set to not select all edges for beveling, while you manually with the _tool_ just said bevel everything, no matter which angle. And that's why you would have to do the same in the _modifier_ by setting _Limit Method_ to _None_.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon - the answer tells me the "how" but your comment tells me the "why". I always like to understand what's going on and very much appreciate this kind of extra information.

Comment: Yeah, you're welcome. I thought so that's why I added this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve the same result with the Bevel-modifier by setting the "Limite Methode" to none.

[image]

The bevel modifier has a lot more features, that's why it is hard to make a "Smart bevel modifier" as your beveling operations are dependent to your desired outcome.